# Java FX Set Margin

Tags: javafx, layout, margin, vbox, hbox

This simple example creates an area with 2 rectangle areas marked in red. 
I want to push the right area by n pixels towards the right using the `VBox` margin method but nothing happens. Why is margin not working in this example ? It works in scene builder though..

```
public class LayoutContainerTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        VBox areaLeft = new VBox();
        areaLeft.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
        areaLeft.setPrefSize(100, 200);

        VBox areaMiddle = new VBox();
        areaMiddle.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
        areaMiddle.setPrefSize(100, 200);

        VBox areaRight = new VBox();
        areaRight.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
        areaRight.setPrefSize(100, 200);

        VBox.setMargin(areaRight, new Insets(0,0,0,50));

        HBox root = new HBox(areaLeft,areaMiddle,areaRight);
        root.setSpacing(30);



        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are using `VBox.setMargin()` but should be using the `HBox` method instead:

```
HBox.setMargin(areaRight, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 50));
```

The reason being, you are setting the margins for the children of a `VBox`, while `areaRight` is the child of a `HBox`. If you were to use your code and then place `areaRight` into a `VBox`, you would be seeing the margin as expected.

You mention that it works in SceneBuilder, but if you inspect the actual FXML code, you'll see that SceneBuilder is correctly using `HBox`:

```
<VBox fx:id="areaRight" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-background-color: red;">
     <HBox.margin>
        <Insets left="50.0" />
     </HBox.margin>
  </VBox>
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast ! Big Thanks. Perfectly clear now.